# Why does my dhcp server assign 2 different IPs to the same client NIC?

Tags: 16.04, networking, dhcp, dhcpd

My dhcpd is getting DHCPREQUEST packages for 2 different IPs from the same MAC address on the same (linux-ubuntu-16.04) client. Snip from the syslog:

```
Jun 20 09:56:13 infranet dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.227 from 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 09:56:13 infranet dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.227 to 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 09:59:41 infranet dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.201 from 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 09:59:41 infranet dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.201 to 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 10:00:28 infranet dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.227 from 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 10:00:28 infranet dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.227 to 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 10:04:05 infranet dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.201 from 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
Jun 20 10:04:05 infranet dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.201 to 0c:c4:7a:91:f6:da (B3) via eth0
```

I have found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168412/dhcp-assigns-2-ips-to-1-mac-address where there is no real solution posted but otherwise looks very similar to what I am experiencing. The client that gets these 2 IPs has

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

in /etc/network/interfaces and also has the network manager disabled via /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
managed=false
```

Is this a fault on the dhcp or the client? How do I find out? I assume it's the client, but I am at a loss as to what was changed on the machine to cause this.

Comment: this is a shot in the dark:  it's not a laptop on a docking station is it?  if I put some thinkpads on a docking station with utp cable attached; they have the same mac address (via docking station) as the onboard [laptop] ethernet & for one thinkpad; the same mac address as the inbuilt wireless adapter as laptop-ethernet and as docking-ethernet.

Comment: Nope. Not a docking station. It really is just 1 NIC with 1 plug on a rather static machine (it's an industry machine with a linux server inside). Also this plug hasn't been unplugged for the past 2 weeks and the issue only appeared yesterday.